# telegram bot как получить ответ по скрипту?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, aiogram

всем привет. тренируюсь в написании ботов, проблема в текущем, что не могу получить ответ от бота после ввода ГАН, скрипт рабочий, в отдельном файле отрабатывает без проблем, но в телеге тишина, подскажите как получить ответ примерно в таком формате -

```
Дата Операция с грузом Дата/время исполнения операции Примечания
18.04.21 Принят на груз.терминал 18.04.21 14:16 Рейс: СУ-1461 По заявке №: 476154 Наименование груза: ОБОРУДОВАНИЕ Мест: 3 Вес: 11
18.04.21 Размещен на складе 18.04.21 14:16 -
18.04.21 Груз отправлен 18.04.21 18:28 Наименование груза: ОБОРУДОВАНИЕ Тип груза: Обычный Мест: 3 Вес: 11 Рейс: СУ-1461 Дата/время вылета: 18.04.21 18:22
```

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет! Напиши мне номер ГАН в формате 555-12345678 и получишь его статус!")


@dp.message_handler(commands=[])
async def get_status(message: types.Message):
    try:
        browser.get('http://miragegw.ovbport.ru:7777/pls/apex/f?p=723:1:0:::::')
        block_gan = browser.find_element_by_id('P1_NOMER').send_keys(message)
        button_search = browser.find_element_by_id('B5691949657452399').click()
        tabs = browser.window_handles
        browser.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
        url_new = browser.current_url
        way = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/section[2]/table')
        status = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#report_R5690543311452393 > tbody.uReportBody > tr > td > table')
        await message.reply(status)
    except:
        await message.reply("Проверь ГАН!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать selenium в ботах под мессенджеры или соцсети это плохая идея из-за его ненадёжности и большого потребления памяти, лучше такой функционал реализовывать на уровне запросов. Данную фичу можно реализовать через [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html), это будет быстрее и надежнее.
Сами запросы можно отследить с помощью инструментов разработчика в браузере или с помощью снифферов-отладчиков (fiddler, charles и тп) при взаимодействии с сайтом через браузер.
[image: Запрос с отправкой номера]
[image: Поля post запроса]
При переходе по ссылке необходимо спарсить все необходимые поля из ответа (через regex, bs4, lxml) и все найденные значения передать через POST запрос.
Код будет выглядеть примерно так, (в коде ниже только схема запросов, осталось парсер значений полей дописать!)

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("http://miragegw.ovbport.ru:7777/pls/apex/f?p=723:1:0:::::") as resp:
            resp = await resp.text()
            # здесь необходимо спарсить значения полей с html страницы для следующего post запроса и поместить в словарь
            #...
            data = {"p_flow_id": 0, "p_flow_step_id": 1, #...
}
        async with session.post("http://miragegw.ovbport.ru:7777/pls/apex/wwv_flow.accept", data=data) as resp:
            resp = await resp.text()
            # далее вытащить данные из ответа
            #...
```

Comment: а как с этой библиотекой вставлять номера и нажимать кнопку поиска по аналоги с селениумум?

Comment: @АлексейГалушкин в этом примере в POST запросе передаётся номер и прочие скрытые поля, тем самым воспроизводится логика заполнения и отправки формы.
Чтобы полностью разобраться в вопросе ознакомьтесь с http протоколом и его методами.